# Wepay Java SDK and GAE is giving an exception

Tags: google-app-engine, wepay

I am using https://github.com/wepay/WePay-Java-SDK,

deploying into GAE, i get the exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

is this a known issue? can anyone explain to me a workaround.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WePay library is not supported in The google Ape Engine. I downloaded the source and updated it using the google HTTP client library. if its a need I can post.